# Properties of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

I have three matrices: $A_{2\times3}$, $B_{3\times3}$ and $C_{1\times3}$, where $B$ is symmetric.

And I have the following multiplication: $A B C^t$ and $C B A^t$.

In the end, what I want is the result of $(A B C^t) (C B A^t)$, which gives a $2\times2$ matrix.

Is there anything that can be said about the result without having to do the actual multiplication?

Comment: Well, you're looking at $D^\top D$, where $D$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix. So, for starters, it has rank $\le 1$ (and therefore has determinant $0$). It is a positive scalar multiple of a projection matrix in $\Bbb R^2$. What do you hope to say in total generality?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya: Yours was not a helpful edit. Almost surely the OP is talking about real (or perhaps complex) matrices, and muddying the waters with an arbitrary field is *not* appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one thing you can say is that the resulting matrix is symmetric.  For the given matrices:

$$
\left(ABC^{T}\right)^{T}=CB^{T}A^{T}=CBA^{T}
$$

Now, let $D=ABC^{T}$, then $D^{T}=CBA^{T}$ as indicated above.

You matrix product is then equivalent to $DD^{T}$.  This is symmetric because

$\left(DD^{T}\right)^{T}=DD^{T}$.

I hope this helps.